# How do I validate individual array elements for length in php?

Tags: php

So I have an html form with an input with a name of "vin[]".  The input is an array.  This is because I have given the user an option to click a button, and on button click I add a clone of the input with a name of "vin[]".  I am doing this because I am collecting the vin number of vehicles and the user needs the option to include multiple vehicles.

So my question is:  In my array of vin numbers, how do I validate that each vin number is exactly 17 characters?  I only want the form to submit if all vin's provided by the user meet this criterion.

I know I have to iterate through my array, and tell the program to display an error message if any of the vins are not 17 characters, I want to use the mail function to send an email if all provided vins are 17 characters..Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($_POST['vin']) as $vin_value ) {
if(strlen($vin_value) != 17) {
  echo "VIN is not 17 digits"; 
  echo "VIN is " . strlen($vin_value) . " digits";
  echo "VIN value is: " . $vin_value;
  } else {
mail($admin_email, "Auto Quote Request", $email_body);
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  }
```

ATTENTION: Contrary to the above notice, this question does not have a correct/relevant duplicate answer.  The only correct answer to this question is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count how many were ok:

```
$ok = 0;
foreach(...) {
   if (strlen($vin_value) == 17) {
     $ok++;
   }
}
if ($ok == count($_POST['vin'])) {
   ... all of them are ok
}
```